# I am trying to open and html file with bs4 and i get this error

Tags: python-3.x, parsing, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

> MarkupResemblesLocatorWarning: The input looks more like a filename than markup. You may want to open this file and pass the filehandle into Beautiful Soup.
> soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc,"lxml")

(sorry for the poor formatting of the question as im still a beginner )

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html_doc="File_Path"
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc,"lxml")
bgs=soup.find_all('img')
print(bgs)
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer and thought it leave it here for anyone who might face the same problem
open the file first before passing it in bs4

```
html_doc=open("filepath")
```

then pass it inside the soup object

```
soup=BeautifulSoup(html_doc,"lxml")
```